# apply_filter and add_filter conflict

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I have a woocommerce website and I use "ProductX - Gutenberg Product Blocks for WooCommerce" to create a product slider.

I need to change the add to cart button to include step quantity for products (I added minimum quantity and step quantity) so I use this function in my functions.php of child theme:

```
function zp_filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $quantity, $product, $args ) { 
    if (is_product_category() ) {
    $quantity = 1;
        $product_step = wc_get_product_step_limit( $product->id);   
        if ($product_step > 1){
        $quantity = $product_step;
        }
        $qty = isset( $args['quantity'] ) && $args['quantity'] == $quantity ? $args['quantity'] : $quantity;
        $html = sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( $qty ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
            isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
    return $html;
    }
    };          
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'zp_filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 99, 3 );
```

This function do it's job very well throughout the site except on the pages where I use the plugin that stops working, for a conflict with this function:

```
public function get_add_to_cart($product , $cart_text = ''){
    $attributes = array(
        'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
        'data-quantity'    => '1',
        'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
        'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
        'rel'              => 'nofollow',
        'class'            => 'add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart',
    ); 
     return apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
        sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" data-stock="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_stock_quantity() ),
            wc_implode_html_attributes( $attributes ),
            $cart_text ? $cart_text : esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        ),
        $product
    ); 
}
```

How can I change my function zp_filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link in order to avoid conflict?
I tried to change priority in add_filter but doesn't work.

EDIT: perhaps the right question is **when** to use add_filter or applay_filter with a core hook

Comment: There’s no conflict. The first function filters the second one. That’s how filters work. The problem is probably that your function is only applying when `is_product_category()`.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie  No, I had to exclude  apply_filters in plugin to let it work, otherwise page using plugin brakes also during editing, but without error, only blank page and no possibility to save.

could it be an execution order problem?

Which is the order of the execution?
plugins > functions themes or functions themes > plugin